# CSS: how to make two sections at the same line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make these wo sections at the same line where the `<ul>` section at right and the `<span>` section, but, I can't find how.

PS: I use here [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
<span>
        <a href="~/AppsMetiers/Ajouter/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:6px;">Nouveau</span></a> |
        <span style="margin-left:5px;"><a href="~/AppsMetiers/Tria/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;"></span></a></span>|
        <span style="margin-left: 5px;"><a href="~/AppsMetiers/Index/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span><span style="margin-left:10px;"></span></a></span>
</span>
```

Any suggestion, please ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2TVE5/)

```
.pagination.pagination-sm + span {
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:25px 0 25px 10px;
}
```

Make the adjacent span element `inline-block`, align it to the top and add margins to match the `.pagination` element. This assumes that the markup will remain the same.

Comment: is it possible to place the `<ul>` at right and the `<span>` at left, please ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding divisions around the two parts, and floating the two divisions next to each other. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathanfrancy/5e3KL/1/). See the CSS to see how to float.

```
<div class="cont-1">
... pagination code ...
</div>

<div class="cont-2">
... span and anchor codes ...
</div>
```

At the end of the code, make sure to clear your floats.

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote this.. but this is what your output looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/5e3KL/ Did you look at your jsFiddle?

Comment: Updated with a new fiddle. All it needed was margins. Still don't understand the downvote.